# Play on tomcat6: jar not loaded. see servlet spec 2.3 section 9.7.2

Tags: playframework, tomcat6, servlet-3.0

Im using Play framework 2.6.2, I generated war file and tried to deploy it on tomcat6, I got this error:

> jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class

Im using servlet 3.0.1 in play framework.

I don't know how I offended the class...
Anyone ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I offended tomcat because my war has tomcat api servlet jar that tomcat is able to load it self...
So I removed the dependency from my configuration in build.sbt